# Using a non-COM object from a COM dll

Tags: c++, dll, com, dllimport, dllexport

A Visual Studio C++ solution is made of 2 projects both in C++:

- Client  produces a client.exe
- Algo produces a algo.dll

Client and Algo communicate together via a COM Layer, hence Algo is a COM dll.

I want to add a function in Algo.dll and call it directly from Client, avoiding the COM Layer, but did not succeed to solve the "unresolved symbol" link errors when building the Client.exe

---

What was tried ?

In the Algo project, I've added the LIBRARY_EXPORT preprocessor definition and the following files:
TestFile.h

```
#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"  LIBRARY_API bool __stdcall TestFunction();
```

TestFile.cpp

```
extern "C"  LIBRARY_API bool __stdcall TestFunction()
{
    return true;
}
```

In the client project, there is a call to TestFunction();

I get an link error when building the client:
unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl TestFunction(void)

Apparently, I do not get correctly how to export/import my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add algo.lib to the linker input files of client.exe

Comment: Link just fine. So the COM calls are resolved without this input library ?

Comment: @Palmira - For com to succeed you basically just need to link (or in fact redefine if your client language is not c++) interface definitions (layout and guids), and coclasses (guids). With Automation/IDispatch, you don't link to nothing, it's called "late-binding". That's the beauty of it, kindof.

Comment: You can document this lib dependency by adding `#pragma comment(lib, "algo.lib")` to the headers when when `LIBRARY_EXPORTS` is not defined.